# How to get context inside the WebView definition?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-context

I want to activate sensor when webview loads a special url so I used `sensorManager.registerListener` inside the webview definition:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("compass")){
        sensorManager.registerListener(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(), compass, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `view.getContext().getApplicationContext()` is not working. What is the standard way to get the context here?

Comment: `view.getContext()` will return the parent `Activity` context .. It should work /

Comment: `registerListener()` does not take a `Context`. It needs a `SensorEventListener` as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Context context;

public Yourclassname(Context context) {//constructor
this.context = context;
```

use that context in your code

```
SensorManager mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.contains("compass")){

sensorManager.registerListener(context, 
compass, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }
}
```

//use this or context according to your clas

Comment: Would you please complete the code to show how I use it in my own code?

Comment: This code doesn't use Yourclassname and doesn't reference to a context.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple

1)Declare the webview

```
 WebView webView;
 webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
```

2)access it with webView.getContext()  and Use it where you need it
Ex

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(webView.getContext(),R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score -1):

In MainActivity.java add the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static MainActivity context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
    }
    public static MainActivity getInstance()
    {
        return context;
    }

}
```

use this context by calling this method

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("compass")){
            sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.getInstance(), compass, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use Activity with `static`.